# Vba combobox using non-active sheet

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a combobox to a userform and the its not an activesheet in excel so not sure how to go about it.

The sheet name is "DoNotPrint - Rate Index" and the values within that sheet to appear in the combobox are the columns C2:AS2.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

   Sheets("DoNotPrint - Rate Index").Range("C2:AS2") = ComboBox1.Value

End Sub
```

I tried this code and the combobox list isn't populating those column when the combobox list button is clicked.

[image: combobox]

Comment: Not sure I understand what "the combobox list isn't popping up when the combobox list button is clicked" means. Would a screenshot help?

Comment: What do you mean by "trying to implement a combobox to the userform"? Is the ComboBox on the UserForm? What is it supposed to do when you change it?

Comment: edited my question

Comment: @Comintern the combobox is on the userform, yes. Just want the user to pick one of the combobox option then that information is put into one of the cells in the excel file

Comment: Try setting the RowSource property of the combo box to `'DoNotPrint - Rate Index'!C2:AS2` in the userform's init event instead of whatever it is you're trying to do in the control's change event.

Comment: The list for the combobox  is in the columns not the rows. So I tried the ColumnSource and its giving me error. I tried the RowSource as you stated and it only show one option from the list.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is for taking what's in the combobox and putting it on the sheet, when it's selected.  But if I understand correctly your issue is you can't get the combobox populated.  Because you are using a single row as your dataset and not a single column you will need to transpose your data.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("C2:AS2"))
End Sub
```

Comment: wat about the sheet name "DoNotPrint - Rate Index" where do I put that?

Comment: @SharathChander if the sheet exists in `ThisWorkbook`, it's better not to refer to it by name. Set the sheet's `(Name)` property to e.g. `RateIndexSheet`, and use `RateIndexSheet.Range` - that way your code won't break if the user renames the tab.